# How can I modify this query with two Inner Joins so that it stops giving duplicate results?

Tags: mysql, group-by, subquery, inner-join

**EDIT:** I will leave the post here as is, but what I really needed to accomplish needed to be reposted.  I didn't explain the problem well enough. After trying again with quite a different starting point, I was able to get the query that I needed.  That is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14658674/using-distinct-inside-join-is-creating-trouble).

**ORIGINAL QUESTION:**
I'm having trouble.  I have looked at similar threads, and I am unable to find a solution specific to this query.  The database is very large, and group by seems to slow it down immensely.

The problem is I am getting duplicate results.  Here is my query which causes duplicates:

```
SELECT 
  itpitems.identifier, 
  itpitems.name, 
  itpitems.subtitle, 
  itpitems.description, 
  itpitems.itemimg, 
  itpitems.mainprice, 
  itpitems.upc, 
  itpitems.isbn, 
  itpitems.weight, 
  itpitems.pages, 
  itpitems.publisher, 
  itpitems.medium_abbr, 
  itpitems.medium_desc, 
  itpitems.series_abbr, 
  itpitems.series_desc, 
  itpitems.voicing_desc,
  itpitems.pianolevel_desc,
  itpitems.bandgrade_desc,
  itpitems.category_code,
  itprank.overall_ranking,
  itpitnam.name AS artist,
  itpitnam.type_code 
FROM itpitems 
  INNER JOIN itprank ON ( itprank.item_number = itpitems.identifier ) 
  INNER JOIN itpitnam ON ( itpitems.identifier = itpitnam.item_number ) 
WHERE mainprice >1
```

The results are actually not complete duplicates.  itpitnam.type_code has a different result in the otherwise duplicated results.

Since adding GROUP BY to the end of the query is causing too much strain on the server (It's searching through about 300,000 records) what else can I do?

Can this be re-written as a sub-query? I just can't figure out how to eliminate the 2nd instances where type_code has changed.

Thank you for your help and assistance.

I also tried SELECT DISTINCT itpitems.identifier,  but this served out the same results and had the duplicates (where type_code was the only difference).  I don't want the second instance where type_code has changed.  I just want one result per identifier regardless of whether or not type_code has multiple instances.

Comment: What column is giving you the duplicates?

Comment: Are the duplicates _really duplicates_, that is all columns are the same?

Comment: they are not really duplicate *I guess*. because when you say duplicate, 2 rows must have the same values for all the columns. If you can add sample record with desired result then we can help you with it. It is hard to help you this way because we don't know results of the query. But, on the other hand, if all values of all columns on multiple record are the same, you can simply add `DISTINCT` keyword on the select statement, eg, `SELECT DISTINCT .....`

Comment: I didn't notice they are not in fact complete duplicates.  The entire result is identical except for itpitnam.type_code. I'm still unsure how to resolve this however.

Comment: Michael, you were right, they were not the same.  type_code is different.  And the results are repeated for every unique instance of type_code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without seeing examples of the output, hard to say. But have you tried the same exact query with a simple `DISTINCT` added to the `SELECT`?

```
SELECT DISTINCT itpitems.identifier, itpitems.name, itpitems.subtitle, itpitems.description, itpitems.itemimg, itpitems.mainprice, itpitems.upc, itpitems.isbn, itpitems.weight, itpitems.pages, itpitems.publisher, itpitems.medium_abbr, itpitems.medium_desc, itpitems.series_abbr, itpitems.series_desc, itpitems.voicing_desc, itpitems.pianolevel_desc, itpitems.bandgrade_desc, itpitems.category_code, itprank.overall_ranking, itpitnam.name AS artist, itpitnam.type_code 
FROM itpitems 
INNER JOIN itprank ON ( itprank.item_number = itpitems.identifier ) 
INNER JOIN itpitnam ON ( itpitems.identifier = itpitnam.item_number ) 
WHERE mainprice >1
```

Comment: This would most likely be your answer your looking for.

Comment: Group by was clocking at over 5 seconds when delivering only 1000 results.  I need to deliver 25000 results without crashing the server.  I think group by was the culprit.  But I'm just basing that off of the few instances that I ran the query and clocked it.

Comment: Thanks.  I have edited.  It might be a good idea to move this to chat.  I'm just now sure how.